# Security Report about "Insecure Content-Type Setting": Does this apply to CSS and JavaScript as well?

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, encoding

I am working through a report of an automated vulnerability scanner. One Item is

> Web Server Misconfiguration: Insecure Content-Type Setting ( 11359 )

It's about not returning the character-set for a given HTML page like so, for example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
```

the reported response in question only gives

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/html
...
```

Now I understand the implications, but what about CSS and especially JavaScript?

**Is the charset of CSS and JavaScript resources strictly defined by a standard?**

What if I have internationalized strings in JavaScript variables? Will those by definition have to be escaped? Or would this case require the declaration of a charset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the charset of CSS and JavaScript resources strictly defined by a standard?

No. It is similarly flexible as with HTML, i.e. can be defined in the style itself, by the embedding HTML or in the HTTP header or even with a byte order mark. If not explicitly defined it might also have a default or might depend on the charset encoding of the embedding document:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" ...>
Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8
```

And the same is true for JavaScript. Thus, you better always specify the charset encoding.

Comment: I have found that the charset on the link element is obsolete. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link

Comment: @Marcel: It might be considered obsolete but it still works, just tested with Firefox and Chrome. There is lots of obsolete stuff in the standards which still can be (ab)used.